# macchanger wlan not working

Tags: wireless

I can change my wlan mac address using macchanger but every time I connect to a network it changes back. I am using these commands:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo macchanger -r wlan0 
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

Comment: did you try, before maccanger, to stop the network-manager (sudo stop network-manager), then use macchanger, then restart the service (sudo start network-manager)?

Answer (score 0):

Try a another network manager tool. I also had a problem with my WiFi on my PC.

I installed `wicd` network manager instead of `network-manager-gnome`.
Go to *Ubuntu Software Center*, search for "network manager" and you will find `wicd`.

Answer (score 0):

Install and run `macchanger` before every network connection. Create the folowing file:

```
## File name /etc/udev/rules.d/70-macchanger.rules
## Set Mac Address for Network Adapters
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", KERNEL=="wlan*" RUN+="/usr/bin/macchanger -m XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX %k"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", KERNEL=="eth*" RUN+="/usr/bin/macchanger -m XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX %k"
```

Replace XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX with the Mac Address you want.